# Custom wrappers around SWIG wrappers

Tags: c#, swig

I try to force SWIG to use my own wrapper around the "default" generated wrappers, here is an example...

I have the following "interface" code :

```
template<typename T>
class Expected
{
public:
   T Value();
};

%template(Expected_Int)   Expected<int>;
%template(Expected_Bool)  Expected<bool>;
%template(Expected_Void)  Expected<void>;
```

And my own C# implementation (my own wrapper)

```
public class Expected
{
  public Expected(Expected_Void private) {...}
}
```

In other classes, I use the Expected return value, like this "Expected setHandle(IViewHandle * handle)" and SWIG generate this code  :

```
public override Expected_Void setHandle(IViewHandle handle) {
    Expected_Void ret = new Expected_Void(luciadsdkPINVOKE.ViewContext_setHandle(swigCPtr, IViewHandle.getCPtr(handle)), true);
    if (luciadsdkPINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw luciadsdkPINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
    return ret;
  }
```

Now, I wish to generate the following C# code (have my own wrapper around SWIG wrappers)

```
public override Expected setHandle(IViewHandle handle) {
    Expected_Void ret = new Expected_Void(luciadsdkPINVOKE.ViewContext_setHandle(swigCPtr, IViewHandle.getCPtr(handle)), true);
    if (luciadsdkPINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw luciadsdkPINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
    return Expected(ret);
}
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks

**THE SOLUTION**

```
%typemap(csout,excode=SWIGEXCODE) Expected<void> {
    IExpected ret = new IExpected($imcall, true);$excode
    return ret;
}
%typemap(cstype) Expected<void> "IExpected"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post it, but I guess your C++ method setHandle looks something like:

```
Expected<void> setHandle(IViewHandle);
```

So, if you just want to modify the return type only for this method, you can set a %typemap(csout), a bit like this:

```
%typemap(csout) Expected<void> MyClass::setHandle %{
  Expected_void ret = $imcall;$excode
  return Expected(ret);
%}
```

I think this should work. Maybe I forgot something, but look arround [this](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CSharp.html#CSharp_typemap_examples), maybe you will find more infos.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

Won't work actually, this is what i meant:

```
%typemap(csout) Expected<void> MyClass::setHandle %{
  Expected ret = new Expected($imcall);$excode
  return ret;
%}
```

Comment: Thanks,

I will add my solution to the post. You're not so far from my solution ;-)

Comment: Ok, I see your solution. If you didn't create the IExpected just to fix this issue it is obviously the best.

Anyway, I noticed I made a mistake in my answer, I edit the post just in case.

Comment: Another tip, just be aware that this typemap will work for all the method that return Expected<void>. To focus on one method you need to specify the method name, like I did.